# How to connect and load files in remote BigInsights HDFS(kerberos authentication enabled) from local pyspark program for processing?

Tags: pyspark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql, biginsights

How to connect and load files in remote BigInsights HDFS(kerberos authentication enabled) from local pyspark program for processing?

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet("hdfs://<<remote_hdfs_host>>:8020/testDirectory")
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: From Linux or Windows? Which version of Spark? Which kind of Spark build *(e.g. "with Hadoop 2.7")*?

Comment: From linux(IBM DSX Spark service), tried both spark 1.6.0 with hadoop 2.7, spark 2.0 with hadoop 2.7. It did't work?

Comment: Did you create a kerberos ticket with `kinit`? And what do you mean by _"it didn't work"_ -- show the error stack, that's the most important information you can provide!